# Install Linux on a phone, replacing Android

Tags: android, linux

I have a project phone, a Moto G6 international for which I unlocked the bootloader.  I'd like to get a Linux distribution on my phone, but not the way people normally recommend.  I do *not* want to run Linux on top of Android, though eventually I may need to simulate an Android environment on top of Linux for certain apps.

I've used Ubuntu, but mostly work with Fedora, and if possible I'd like to have all one distribution for my computers.

Which Linux distro would I have the easiest time with?  I'd like it to have common cell phone apps such as a phone dialer and a text messager.

Thanks from the Woodsman

Comment: Did you ever find any solution or path forward? I have different hardware - I like the BLŰ brand - but am pretty POed by how when I get new hardware I _always_ have some POS software to deal with that seems to be written by children, NOT someone ho uses the stuff they're writing! -ugh!- ... like having to use a finger swirl input when it's just flipping NUMERALS! How about I just punch in the damned numerals?! -ACK!- ... You get it, I'm SURE! ... Any luck so far? I'm about to risk bricking a new phone!

Comment: I've bought several phones, only to find there's some bizarre model that I bought causing it not to be rootable. You have to be extremely careful what phone you buy. I got an unlocked and rootable Google Pixel 4. Rarely do you get enough information to know before purchase that the phone will be rootable. Your best bet to get a good rootable phone is to get an EE degree, a fab plant and the ability to order necessary parts to make your own phone and *not* restrict it to a horrible version of Android. I think the NSA has more access to your phone than you do.

Comment: ...I'm with you! SAME experience / frustration. I was thinking that BECAUSE of this issue, we NEED a new community here at Stack Exchange just for "Phone computing" to distinguish it from the "noise" of Android / IPhone, et al. ...Those are valid topics, of course, but THIS "community, to which you and I belong doesn't really have a home - a place to learn from each other on! ARG! ... Want to start a community? Here's a pointer on how: https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1490/how-do-i-create-a-new-community-on-stack-exchange?newreg=72892e31684b4bad98f40b76569f9799

Comment: @RichardT I'll join if it happens. It was SO hard to get a phone capable of installing a different OS. Too many general answers. Too phone phones wherein the US models were shit but they don't say which. I could rebuild a desktop OS far easier. Hate how phones work.

Answer (score 1):

An "[Ubuntu Touch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Touch)" device, or a Phone with "[Firefox OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_OS)", or "[Maemo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maemo)" (OS), might work  for you, but many of the devices that support these products have been discontinued and must be purchased second hand.

You can also install the Termux app and do a lot of linux-like stuff.